# If I have five levels of a categorical predictor, is there any way to get coefficients for each level?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I have a categorical predictor with five levels. Every coding scheme I find produces four coefficients. What should I do if I don't have a natural reference level, and would like to see the effect of each level of the factor (as compared to the mean)?

I'll also add that this is a linear mixed effects model. Here is some code.

```
set.seed(3)

library(data.table)
library(lme4)

a <- rep(1:5, times = 20)
ppt <- rep(101:110, each = 10)
item <- rep(1:10, times = 10)
dv <- rnorm(n = 100)

data <- data.table(cbind(ppt, item, a, dv))

data$ppt <- as.factor(data$ppt)
data$item <- as.factor(data$item)
data$a <- as.factor(data$a)

m <- lmer(dv ~ a + (1|ppt) + (1|item), data = data)
```

Edit:

Changing the reference level changes the values of all coefficients.

```
data$a <- relevel(data$a, ref="2")
m2 <- lmer(dv ~ a + (1|ppt) + (1|item), data = data)
```

Comment: In dealing with category values, R will split the regression into n-1 variables, where the first category is always present and the remaining categories are either present(1) or absent(0).  The intercept is the coefficient for the first level.  To calculate the value for the second level, it is the intercept+a2 coefficient.  The third level is intercept+a3 coefficient.

Comment: @Dave2e Is this still true if there are other predictors in the model, and if there are random intercepts in the model?

Comment: This code still seems to use treatment contrasts instead of deviation contrasts. With treatment contrasts everything will necessarily change as the reference level (the intercept) changes. The intercept is independent of reference level with deviation contrasts. The syntax for changing reference levels and contrasts can be tricky and can require checking to make sure that what you intended actually happened, but I was successful in implementing the workaround suggested in my answer with deviation contrasts.

Comment: Am I correct that this is how to use deviation contrasts: contrasts(data$a) = contr.sum(4)? 

And that this would then set a different reference level: data$a <- relevel(data$a, ref="2")?

Comment: The `contr.sum(4)` evaluation gives you the contrast matrix for a predictor with 4 levels. You have 5 in this example. Instead of struggling with this yourself to get the contrast matrix into the model, you can specify the type of contrast to the linear model fit itself, with the `contrasts` parameter setting. For example, within your call to lmer, specify the parameter setting `contrasts=list(a="contr.sum")` and this will be done automatically for you with the right number of levels.

Comment: In terms of re-leveling, it's the _last_ level that serves as reference for `contr.sum()` so you need to bring the 5th level up to see a value for it. Also, I think that `lmer` reports fixed coefficients in terms of the numerical ordering within the factor, rather than reporting the assigned level names. So if you relevel the report will be confusing if you use text versions of integers as level names. When I re-leveled to make "5" the  first level, its coefficient value was reported as "a1," bearing no relationship to its character name as "5".

Answer (score 1):

The treatment-contrast default in R, which uses one level of a categorical predictor as reference and describes other levels in comparison against that reference, is not your only choice. This [UCLA IDRE web page](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/) goes into detail on 9 different ways to set up a design matrix for categorical variables. As you "would like to see the effect of each level of the factor (as compared to the mean)," [deviation coding](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#DEVIATION) would be the way to go. In R, the `contr.sum()` function provides the design matrix for deviation coding.

Note, however, that you might need to be careful in interpreting those values. The overall mean of your data points will necessarily depend on the relative numbers and mean values of each of the groups, and might not necessarily be representative of what's going on in the population. With `contr.sum()` for deviation coding, the reported intercept against which levels are compared is instead the mean among all levels *unweighted* by the number in each group, as noted in the UCLA IDRE web page. Then again, that might not be representative of what's going on in the population.

With 5 levels of a categorical predictor you will still only get 5 parameter values returned, that intercept and coefficients for differences of 4 of the 5 levels from the intercept. A simple work-around if you want to get a corresponding value for the reference level (the last level, with `contr.sum()`) is to change the reference level of the factor and repeat the analysis. You will lose the coefficient for the new reference level but will gain that for the former reference level while the others remain the same.

Some find the approaches provided by the [`emmeans` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=emmeans) useful in situations involving unbalanced designs, as it weights all cells in a design equally. It has extensive facilities for analysis and prediction with many types of models, and the package author frequently visits this site. As a comment from @rvl points out, that package provides a particularly simple solution to your problem. After you use the `emmeans()` function on your regression model object `m`, the `contrast()` function applied to the resulting `emmGrid` object provides what you are looking for as the default contrast, `eff.emmc`, comparing all levels against the average over all levels.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I use deviation coding (contrasts(data$a) = contr.sum(4) for the sample data) I still only get coefficients for four levels. Would this be different for the emmeans package?

Comment: @Dave I was a bit misleading in my prior explanation of what deviation coding does. I've fixed that, and provided a work-around for getting the deviation of the original reference level from the intercept of the model.

Comment: Hi @EdM thanks again for the reply. When I've tried changing the reference level, the other coefficients change as well. See edit.

Comment: Additionally, emmeans works nicely, but it still gives me pairwise comparisons among predictors. Is there a way to make it give me comparisons of emms to the grand mean?

Comment: I don't have much practical experience with `emmeans`, just thought I would suggest it as an alternate way to do these analyses that directly provides one estimate per level. Typically the estimated marginal means themselves (obtained with the `emmeans()` function applied to your model) and pairwise comparisons among them are of more interest than deviations from the grand mean, particularly given the ambiguity noted in the answer about what "mean" means with imbalanced data. With point estimates and standard errors you can test differences from any particular value you choose.

Comment: @Dave as you are interested in a mixed model you also will have to deal with how to define the standard errors for fixed effects, as needed for statistical comparison against a "mean" value (however you define it). For models fit by the default REML there is a good deal of discussion about how to define the degrees of freedom for fixed effects. Another advantage of the `emmeans` package is that it acknowledges those issues and provides ways to apply several alternatives. See [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/sophisticated.html) for examples.

Comment: Look at the documentation in **emmeans** for ‘contrast()‘ and `eff.emmc`. In short, specifying “eff” contrasts gives comparisons of each mean with the grand mean.

Comment: @Dave in case you weren’t notified about the comment from rvl, see it for the best and simplest answer to your question especially if you’re using a mixed model.

Comment: @rvl Thanks very much for the answer!

Comment: @EdM Thanks for prompting me! I hadn't gotten an alert.

Answer (score 0):

When I have five levels of a categorical variable and all are of equal importance, I simply choose the one with the highest amount of observations as my base.

If you want to add the mean as a base, simply add the mean value as a level in your categorical variable and choose that as the base.

I don't know how to do this in R as I use Stata, but another way (statistically) would be to dichotomize your categorical variable into five variables, adding the mean value as a sixth variable and then including the five variables in the model but not the sixth (mean). This would be equivalent to selecting it as a base.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you explain a bit more how you would add the mean value? Do you mean adding a new row that has that value? Woudl that still work with mixed effects (i.e., what participant/item would that level belong to)?

Comment: To be sure I understand you, if we assume this is your data set: https://prnt.sc/qvtgu6

And categorical is your categorical variable, you want to run a mixed model in which instead of using the default 0 value (first value) as a base, you want to assign the mean value of something instead. What mean value would that be? Would it be the mean value of one of the other variables?

Comment: Yep exactly. I would like to compare to the mean across all observations.

Comment: The mean of what exactly? As you see the categorical variable only has 4 values. 0, 1, 2 or 3. The mean of this set of data would not be a good base. Do you mean you want the mean of "independent2" for example?

Comment: In this case, the mean of 'dependent'.